# Join digits from integer array into one number in Golang?

Tags: go

I have an array of integers:

```
nums := []int{1, 2, 3}
```

How could I make integer 123 out of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I appreciate @KelvinS' approach, there already exists a `math.Pow` (though it deals in float64s.  Never-the-less, his approach breaks down what you are really after, which is raising each successive number (from the right) by an order of magnitude and summing the numbers.  As such, the most straight forward approach I can think of is

```
func sliceToInt(s []int) int {
    res := 0
    op := 1
    for i := len(s) - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        res += s[i] * op
        op *= 10
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(sliceToInt(nums))
}
```

`sliceToInt` is poorly named, but you should get the idea.

https://play.golang.org/p/JS96Nq_so-

It may be a micro optimization to try to get this as fast as possible, but if it happens to be in a hot path it might be worth it

```
BenchmarkPow-8              100000000           13.5 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkJoin-8              5000000           272 ns/op           8 B/op          5 allocs/op
BenchmarkBuffer-8            2000000           782 ns/op         160 B/op          8 allocs/op
BenchmarkSliceToInt-8       200000000            8.65 ns/op        0 B/op          0 allocs/op
PASS
```

Comment: I think @sberry has the best answer. I'd be tempted to simplify further and use `for _, x in s` and `res = 10*res + x`

Comment: What happens with `nums := []int{1, 20, 3}`? :)

Comment: Good point @MartinGallagher! One could argue that 20 is not a digit. It depends on what the requirements really are. Concat a bunch of arbitrary numbers, or reassemble a series of digits back into a number? We don't know; it wasn't specified.

Comment: if the slice contains a large set of items then it will go out of range and you'll end up with the wrong value. But for this use case it works. I ended up using `big.NewInt` for my use case.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "log"
)

func join(nums []int) (int, error) {
    var str string
    for i := range nums {
        str += strconv.Itoa(nums[i])
    }
    num, err := strconv.Atoi(str)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    } else {
        return num, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3}
    num, err := join(nums)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    } else {
        log.Println(num)
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to do this, but this example works.

Answer (score 2):

You can also iterate over the slice and build the int with arithmetic

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Pow(a, b int) int {
    result := 1
    for i := 0; i < b; i++ {
        result *= a
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{1, 2, 3}
    num := 0
    length := len(nums)
    for i, d := range nums {
        num += d * Pow(10, length-i-1)
    }
    fmt.Println(num)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your slice and add each item to a buffer:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
nums := []int{1, 2, 3}
for i := range nums {
    buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d", nums[i]))
}
```

You can then convert it into an integer using the strconv package.

```
i, err := strconv.Atoi(buf.String())
```

GoPlay here:
https://play.golang.org/p/8w-gc2S2xR

Comment: I think they're trying to get an int, not a string

Comment: Good catch, thanks. Updated to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

To me the simplest approach is:

1) Convert slice of ints to slice of strings

2) Join the strings

3) Convert resulting string into an int

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func sliceToInt(ints []int) int {
    stringVals := make([]string, len(ints))

    for ind, val := range ints {
        stringVals[ind] = strconv.Itoa(val)
    }

    newInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(strings.Join(stringVals, ""))

    return newInt

}

func main() {
    s1 := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(sliceToInt(s1))

    s2 := []int{1, 20, 3}
    fmt.Println(sliceToInt(s2))
}
```

Result:

```
123
1203
```

Converting slice of ints to strings, and then joining is O(N), as opposed to incrementally building out the final string, which is O(N * N).